# Problems installing an add in for OWA(Outlook Web App) as the add-in isn't supported by the version of Exchange Server

Tags: installation, vsto, outlook-addin, visual-studio-addins, outlook-web-app

I am trying to install a custom Outlook add-in for the OWA, however when I attempt to install the XML manifest file I receive an error stating that the app isn't supported by the current version of Exchange Server.

There is not an XML file in the application folder by default, so in order to comply with the request for an XML, I changed the file extension of the Manifest file from .manifest to .XML.

The OWA custom add-in installer does not seem to recognize this as the correct file.

Which file should I use, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Web add-in projects don't create a .manifest file; is this a VSTO project?

Comment: It is yes. I hadn't thought of this previously somehow but from your response I gather that I will have to create a "web add in" instead of VSTO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OWA can't run VSTO add-ins. Instead, you need to create a Mail App (so-called Outlook Add-in). See [Get Started with Outlook add-ins for Office 365](https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted) for more information.

Comment: Hello, I get a similar error when I try to install an office app on exchange 2013 on prem. Same app works fine in Office 365. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You need to check whether a particular add-in schema is supported by the host.